# View data from foreach in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

First of all forgive me I'm a very beginner to the codeigniter framework. I want to display all the sub contents of parent array in the view. I assume that my data retrieving part is done and now I need to know how to get values by using foreach. I used foreach but I'm getting errors (Illegal string offset). Here is the var_dump values that I am getting to my page.

```
array(1) {
  ["post"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(2) "52"
    ["status"]=>
    string(29) "This is a test status update."
    ["user"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["time"]=>
    string(19) "2015-02-05 19:47:42"
    ["modified"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["comment"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["comment_id"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["comment"]=>
        string(22) "This is a test comment"
        ["comment_datetime"]=>
        string(19) "2015-02-06 08:36:15"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["comment_id"]=>
        string(1) "5"
        ["comment"]=>
        string(11) "sdfsdfsdfds"
        ["comment_datetime"]=>
        string(19) "2015-02-06 09:33:25"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried by getting data like this:

```
<?php
    foreach($post as $data){
     $data['status'];
     $data['post_id'];
    }
?>
```

But, when I do this I'm getting illegal string offset error message.

Comment: try to print the values with  in foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

if you look clearly at the data

```
 $data['post_id'];
```

is not in your array, it is there in the data within the  $data['post'], there are arrays within array.. so you need to look for the data accordingly.

In order to access keys and values in the code, you can use

```
  foreach($post as $key=>$value){
  // $key will have the keys and $value will have the corresponding values 
  }
```

Comment: How do I define $key and $value?

Answer (score 1):

before you pass the data to the view put current($dataset) and pass it to view. So you can access it by $post['commnents']

```
$this->load->view('your_view_name',current($data_set_passing));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
foreach ($post['post'] as $data)
```

If the array you are printing is called $post, as you can see this is a nested array.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php
    foreach($post as $data){
     $data['post']['status'];
     $data['post']['post_id'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the posts array is associate array , you better use $posts['post'] instead in foreach . here is the link i shared to get it solved http://goo.gl/W7JgAQ

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?php
    foreach($post->result_array() as $data){
     $data['status'];
     $data['post_id'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will get the result as you want:

```
foreach($posts as $data)
    {

        echo $data['post_id'];
        echo $data['status'];
        echo $data['user'];
        echo $data['time'];
        echo $data['modified'];
        foreach($data['comment'] as $sub)
            {
                echo $sub['comment_id'];
                echo $sub['comment'];
                echo $sub['comment_datetime'];
            }
    }
```